# Best way to listen for cmd + shift + z and cmd + z using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events, keydown

I am trying to implement redo and undo in a browser. I have a solution that works, but it sometimes misinterprets the redo sequence as undo, whereas this never happens, for example, in vscode. My code is as follows:

```
document.addEventListener(
  'keydown',
  async function(evt) {
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation()
    if (
      evt.code === 'KeyZ' &&
      (evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey) &&
      evt.shiftKey
    ) {
      // handle redo action
    } else if (evt.code === 'KeyZ' && (evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey)) {
      // handle undo action
    }
  })
```

I am aware of other questions similar to this one, but they all offer solutions similar to mine. I am specifically looking for a solution that will never misinterpret an undo/redo, so that, for example, a sequence of 50 actions can be undone and redone with perfect precision (as is the case in vscode, and probably countless other browser-based tools).

Answer (score 4):

You're in the right direction, but a few things:

1. You can't use `async` for the event listener callback. Calls to callback function in [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) are **synchronous**.
2. It is recommended to use [`evt.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of [`evt.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code). (On the bright side, you don't need to start key arguments with `"Key*"`)
3. The following items in the list below are Boolean. If they are pressed, their value is `true`, otherwise they are `false`.

   - `evt.shiftKey`
   - `evt.altKey` (Option/⌥ on Mac)
   - `evt.ctrlKey`
   - `evt.metaKey` (Command/⌘ on Mac)

You can learn more about how modifier keys are detected on at MDN on the [`evt.getModifierState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState) page. Character code can be found using [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), but you'll probably not need to use it.

4. In your code example, you'll also need to use `window` instead of `document` to call this event.

This should fix your code sample.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (evt.key === 'Z' && (evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey) && evt.shiftKey) {
      // handle redo action
    } else if (evt.key === 'Z' && (evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey)) {
      // handle undo action
    }
});
```

Comment: One optimization: 

evt.key === 'Z' | evt.key === 'z'

For upper and lower case

Comment: Please DO NOT use evt.key for shortcut. it doesn't work on non-English keyboards.